# Problem with get method of a nested data model FastAPI

Tags: mongodb, fastapi

I´m developing a project (Angularjs for the front, FastAPI and MongoDB for the back) about **Practical Cases** and I've come across the following issue: when I try to use the *get* method to retreive all the cases the following error appears:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Case
response -> 0 -> id
str type expected (type=type_error.str)
```

My data models are as follows:

```
from typing import Optional, List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Answer(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 required: bool
 value: int


class SubOption(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 answer: Answer


class Option(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 suboption: Optional[List[SubOption]]
 answer: Answer


class SubMenu(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 option: List[Option]


class Menu(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 submenu: List[SubMenu]

class Case(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 menu: List[Menu]
```

The methods:

```
def practicalCase(case) -> dict:
return{
     "id": case["_id"],
      "description": case["description"],
      "menu": case["menu"]
}

def listCases(entity) -> list:
return [clinicalCase(case) for case in entity]
```

And the CRUD operations:

```
@case.get('/cases', response_model=list[Case], tags=["case"])
async def all_cases():
    return listCases(ven.local.cases.find())

@case.post('/newcases', response_model=Case, tags=["case"])
async def new_case(case: Case):
    case_new = dict(case)
    del case_new["id"]
    json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(case_new) 
    id = ven.local.cases.insert_one(json_compatible_item_data).inserted_id
    case = ven.local.cases.find_one({"_id": id})

    ven.local.cases.find_one({"_id": id})
```

I´ve tried many different things, from adjusting the data models using Field(...) to trying to apend the menu dict to the case dict, but to no aveil.

Any kind of help/hint would be welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any sense:

```py
def practicalCase(case) -> dict:
return{
     "id": menu["id"],
      "description": menu["description"],
      "submenu": menu["submenu"]
}

def listCases(entity) -> list:
return [clinicalCase(case) for case in entity]
```

The parameter `case` is never used in `practicalCase`, but you use variable name `menu`? The same goes voor `listCases()`, where you expect a parameter with name `entity` but are referencing `case`.

Secondly, this:

```py
class Case(BaseModel):
 id: str
 description: str
 menu: List[Menu]
```

expects an id of type `str`, while I am betting that you are using `int`? It's impossible to tell for sure though.

Comment: 1. Yeah you're right, I got it mixed up, the actual code uses `case` instead of `menu` inside the return statement. I'll update the code in my post

2. Actually no, i dont use `int` in the id

Comment: Sorry I looked at it again, and what probably is going on is that the returned documents from mongo have an `id_` (or `_id`, don’t recall precisely).  You can try to alias the field in your model

Comment: I finaly, with the help of a frind, found what was the problem. The `id` inside the `def` has to be a `str` , like this: `"id: str(case["_id"])`